# My unit tests don't work with multiple databases

Tags: python, django, multiple-databases

I'm working on a project where there are two databases, and I need to create unit tests for my models and etc.

these are my databases:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {},
    'auth_db': {
        'NAME': 'name'
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'user'
        'PASSWORD': 'password'
        'PORT': 5432
        'HOST': 'localhost
    },
    'base': {
        'NAME': 'name,
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'PORT': 5432,
        'HOST': 'locahost,

    }
}
```

At first I'm creating only the unit tests of the models

```
from django.test import TestCase
from base.models import User

class UserModelTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # Set up non-modified objects used by all test methods
        User.objects.create(first_name='Big', last_name='Bob')

    def test_first_name_label(self):
        author = User.objects.get(id=1)
        field_label = author._meta.get_field('first_name').verbose_name
        self.assertEqual(field_label, 'first name')
```

But when I do `sudo python3 manage.py test`, it returns me the error:

```
AssertionError: Database queries to 'base' are not allowed in this test. Add 'base' to base.tests.test_models.UserModelTest.databases to ensure proper test isolation and silence this failure.
```

When I was working with just one database, it wasn't giving a problem, however, when I separated it, I had this problem. I've looked everywhere and haven't found a solution.

Comment: Can you try the same by adding router for different databases?

Comment: seprate the settings file and create project/settings/test.py and mention all the setting for test there now run  'python manage.py --settings=project.settings.test'